# Command button for multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets. On every sheet is command button.

I want on one sheet to take action on other two.

Can You give me some tips what should I do? Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("J9:J137")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = 0 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("J9:J137")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = 0 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. U can create 3 subs with the code of each botton and in the code of botton one u can Just call the three subs

Answer (score 0):

Think I found solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button8_Click()
    Dim xSh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each xSh In Worksheets
        xSh.Select
        Call CommandButton2_Click
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("J9:J137")
       If cell.Value = 0 Then
           cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
       End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("J9:J137")
       If cell.Value = 0 Then
           cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If You got 3 sheets: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 and on the first You got a button, which is calling button actions on other 2 sheets assign below code to the button on Sheet1:

```
Sub ButtonOnFirstSheet()

Call CommandButton1_Click
Call CommandButton2_Click

End Sub
```

and would like to modify a little bit your code to be sure it will appeal to correct sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each cell In .Range("J9:J137")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = 0 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim cell As Range
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    For Each cell In .Range("J9:J137")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = 0 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```